# Magento 2 does not import configurable products

Tags: magento, magento2, configurable-product

When I create a **configurable** product through `Products > Catalog > Add Product`, everything works well. During the process of creating this product I add 3 configurations.

The product is visible in the front-end and there are 3 options available. However, when I do an export, delete all products and re-import my products; the products are imported, but the configurable product does not have any visible relation with the virtual products. Also, the product is not visible in the front-end (store).

The import file can be viewed in [this PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/E62iwfDr).

Answer (score 0):

Use this file https://www.dropbox.com/s/ldqa4hey9b5vclf/import.csv?dl=0 to import configurable product in magento2.

Make sure as per file you must have a product dropdown attribute with name "size" and options S, M, L.

You can add additional column as per your requirement.

This is a standard file with minimum required column to import configurable product in magento2.

I have tested this file in latest magento 2.1.8 and it is working fine for me.